# Запуск JavaFX приложения в браузере

Tags: javafx

Подскажите как запустить JavaFX приложение в браузере. Раз с версии 8 JavaFX входит в стандартную Java, то получается можно его запускать через апплет. Но, например, говорят что Google Chrome отключил возможность запуска апплетов. По старому через jnlp-файл, запустить JavaFX приложение у меня пока не получается. Если можно скиньте пример запуска JavaFX приложения в браузере.

Comment: ...вспомнил картинку про троллейбус из хлеба... зачем это?

Comment: К примеру у меня есть игра, зачем мне ее распространять в виде exe-файла или jar. Проще же в браузере разместить приложение. Тем более я планирую использовать БД. Или это делается как-то по другому?

Comment: Нежели чем бороться с мельницами при интеграции теплого в мягкое, лучше использовать родные для браузера методы, будет проще

Comment: Можно поподробнее? Пока я знаю несколько вариантов - это флеш, апплеты, возможно еще на JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Продолжая предложение Stranger:

Я совершенно согласен. Если на десктопе еще более менее можно сделать, на вебе ни в коем случае! Используйте лучше [ThreeJS](http://threejs.org/).

А вобще сейчас развелось очень много движков под веб. Уж что-нибудь для себя найдете.